# codeigniter default controller url routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I am putting together a simple networking site and would like to have the urls work similar to facebook so by typing in domain.com/username I would get a user profile. I can do this already this way

Logged in users profile at

```
domain.com/
```

other users profile at

```
domain.com/home/username
```

The default controller is called home and I am currently using the _remap function to check for extra url parameters to display different data based on what is or isn't passed.

My question is how would I map this out so I can access user profiles by:

```
domain.com/username
```

Is there a routes.php setting I could use? htaccess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should add the following rule in your config/routes.php

```
// Profile Route
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/$1';
```

**this will reroute all your request to the home controller**.

so `domain/michelle` will re be rerouted as `domain/home/michelle` 
but in this case all your requests will be rerouted to the home controller
eg. `domain/pages/about` will also be rerouted to `domain/home/pages/about` wich false.

```
domain/michelle => domain/home/michelle // TRUE
domain/pages/about => domain/home/pages/about // FALSE
```

**so you MUST add for each request a identic rule before the Profile Route**,
eg. `$route['pages/(:any)']  = 'pages/$1';`

put it all together :

```
// Page Route 
$route['pages/(:any)']  = 'pages/$1'

// Last Profile Route
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/$1';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the easiest thing to do in Codeigniter.
To do so you need first you need to define all the routes you use in routes.php and to the end of file you need to add line, that will send all other requests to your controller that will check if user exists.

```
$route['stores/(:any)'] = 'stores/$1';
$route['pages/(:any)'] = 'pages/$1'; 

$route['(:any)'] = "home/$1"; //this route will return user's page
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by modifying the routes.php file available in application/config file. To learn more about routes.php. Here is the link [URI routing in Codeigniter](http://www.phpsyntax.blogspot.in/2012/08/uri-routing-in-codeigniter.html)