# Converting apache's .htaccess file to Nginx .config file

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have this system developed in codeigniter on the localhost I am able to load it without writing the controller name as **localhost/ecommerce/** but once I upload it to the online Nginx server I have to load it as **tushibe.com/shopController** instead of **tushibe.com/**
What could I be doing wrong?
Herer is my .htaccess code

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
 </IfModule>
```

And this is my routes code

```
     <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
      $route['default_controller'] = "shopController";
      $route['404_override'] = '';
      $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;;
     /* End of file routes.php */
  /* Location: ./application/config/routes.php */
```

I have also changed the config file 
replacing

```
    $config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

with

```
    $config['index_page'] = "";
```

After some intense research I have realized that nginx seamingly does not iunderstand .htaccess files and I therefore need to convert them to Nginx .config files. As I am totally new to nginx, I have no idea how this is done I would therefore like to ask

1. What name and extension will the file take?
2. Where will it be placed in my folder structure?

Comment: Is your problem solved ?

Comment: @GaneshAher Not yet

Comment: In your .htaccess file replace this RewriteBase /  with RewriteBase /shopController

Comment: That has not solved it and I have noted that the issue is with nginx server as it works correctly on my localhost that is an apache server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add the following rule in your config/routes.php

```
// Profile Route
$route['(:any)'] = 'shopController/$1';
```

This will reroute your request, and send your request through `tushibe.com/shopController`.

Hope this will help you.

refer to this question: [codeigniter default controller url routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928893/codeigniter-default-controller-url-routing)

Comment: Check URI Routing in documentation: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: This has not helped